# C++ runtime_exception with string + integer

Tags: c++, string, exception, integer

In C++ I am throwing a run time exception like below,

```
throw std::runtime_error("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvq"+12);
```

The exception that is thrown doesn't have the initial few characters.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  mnopqrstuvq
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Can someone explain this behavior ?

Things work fine if I use the below stmt to throw the exception

```
throw std::runtime_error("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvq"+std::to_string(12));
```

Comment: `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvq"+12` should cut off the firest 12 characters from the string since its a pointer increment operation. It amounts to take the address of the string literal and add 12 to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the definitions for `runtime_error` takes a `const char*`, which is what you are passing it. This section of code:

```
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvq"+12
```

Takes the pointer to this `const char*` and increments it by 12 (which happens to be `m` in the string).

When you do this:

```
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvq"+std::to_string(12)
```

you are invoking the `operator+(const char*, std::string)` function which returns a string (specifically `"abc...12"`), thereby calling the `runtime_error(std::string&)` declaration.

Answer (score 2):

The literal `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvq"` is actually just a pointer to an array of `char const`.

Adding `12` to it gives a pointer `12` positions ahead, which is `"mnopqrstuvq"`.